# how to install hark on ros-electric

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all
i try to install hark on ros-electric whit this link : http://www.ros.org/wiki/hark
but This link is broken ,
can body help me to install hark on ros electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12270/how-to-install-hark-on-ros-electric/) by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-08**:
Please be clearer what link is broken.  The above link works fine for me. And so does the follow up link to electric installation instructions.

**Comment by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) on 2012-03-12**:
yes this link work fine , but svn download link in this page in broken , when i try to download svn link in this page that show this error : The requested URL /svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/hark was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the link at the bottom for installation, under the Installation header.  You can file a ticket for them to update their manifest url which is rendered at the top.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1